# Validation errors not shown with model driven forms in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am using the below code for validation errors but no error message is seen. Can anyone help. I have set the validators in component using Form builder.

When i am using only one form - group it works, but not working with nest form- groups.

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

import {ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="login">
<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="dologin(form.value)">
 <div class="form-group" formGroupName="user" id ="user">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" formControlName="username">

        <div [hidden]="registerForm.controls['username'].valid || registerForm.controls['username'].pristine"
        class="alert alert-danger"> Username is required.</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" [formControl]="registerForm.controls['password']">
        <div [hidden]="registerForm.controls['password'].valid || registerForm.controls['password'].pristine"
        class="alert alert-danger"> Password is required.</div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" (click)="logOut([registerForm])">Check vals</button>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!registerForm.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>
</div>
  `,
  providers: [FormBuilder]
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  form: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
    this.registerForm=this.fb.group({
        user:this.fb.group({
          username:['',Validators.required]
        }),
        password:['',Validators.required]
    });
  }

  logOut(x: any) {
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
      console.log(x[i]);
    }
  }

  dologin(stuff: any) {
    console.log(stuff);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Please tag angular 2/4 questions under `angular` tag and not `angularjs` (Use angularjs only for version 1.xX) - I already retagged this question. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please try following changes

```
<div *ngIf="registerForm.get('user.username').hasError('required') && registerForm.get('user.username').touched"
        class="alert alert-danger"> Username is required.</div>
```

and to show password error

```
<div *ngIf="registerForm.get('password').hasError('required') && registerForm.get('password').touched"
        class="alert alert-danger"> Password is required.</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks. :)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks. :)

Comment: Nice, never tried this solution with `user.username` +1 :)

Comment: @AJT_82 What about `registerForm.hasError('required', 'user.username')`?  :))

Comment: @developer033 Sorry for late answer, but I have been outside the world of Angular, and thrown into the deep waters of AngularJS for the past week, I think I don't even remember Angular anymore, hah. Luckily I'm back now in the safe and comfortable world of Angular :D Yeah, so that was the chitchat! So no, have not tried that either :) I guess I haven't been smart enough to figure such a thing out to use `user.username` in any such case :P

Comment: @AJT_82 no problem haha.. I'm just asking myself why ppl don't suggest (in general) to use the 2nd. parameter of `hasError` or `getError`. It seems like a hidden parameter(feature) :D I really prefer to use `ctrl hasError('error', 'path')` than `ctrl.get('path').hasError('error')` **even if isn't a nested path** :)

Comment: @developer033, Seems I'm still in an AngularJS mist and not paying attention :D But I see what you mean now. I'm surely gonna adapt what you suggested. Remember looking at blog posts in the past as well regarding validation, seems like everyone is using different techniques. Haven't stumbled upon what you suggested, i.e `ctrl.hasError('error', 'path')` (I think) But I like it and will use it in future, so thanks for that! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you have a nested formgroup, you need to include it to your property path. You do not have a form control with path:

```
registerForm.controls['username']
```

but it should be:

```
registerForm.controls.user.controls.username
```

This can become rather long, so you could think of making a variable that corresponds to this formcontrol, so that template would look cleaner. But that is just a detail :)

**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/TEmoybTLYqA8KHlLW1Dk?p=preview)**

Comment: Getting error with this: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined

Comment: Maybe needing to use safe navigation operator if the property paths are long, one more reason why I like to shorten them and use local variables like I've done in plunker :) In component e.g `this.usernameCtrl = this.registerForm.controls.user.controls.username;` and then use that `usernameCtrl` in the template. But the answer you accepted is a good solution too! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

import {ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators} from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="login">
<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="dologin(form.value)">
 <div class="form-group" formGroupName="user" id ="user">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" formControlName="username">

        <div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.user.controls.username.valid || registerForm.controls.user.controls.username.pristine"
        class="alert alert-danger"> Username is required.</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" formControlName="password" [formControl]="registerForm.controls.password">
        <div [hidden]="registerForm.controls.password.valid || registerForm.controls.password..pristine"
        class="alert alert-danger"> Password is required.</div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" (click)="logOut([registerForm])">Check vals</button>
    <button type="submit" [disabled]="!registerForm.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</form>
</div>
  `
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  registerForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
    this.registerForm=fb.group({
        user:fb.group({
          username:['',Validators.required]
        }),
        password:['',Validators.required]
    });
  }

  logOut(x: any) {
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
      console.log(x[i]);
    }
  }

  dologin(stuff: any) {
    console.log(stuff);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, ReactiveFormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}`enter code here`
```

Modified the name of the form variable to registerForm in component and also imported Formcontrol

Comment: try this and let me know if u get any other issues

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace : `formGroupName="user"` with `[formGroup]=registerForm.controls['user']` 
 And when u try to hide the validation message use  : `[hidden]="registerForm.controls['user'].controls.username.valid"` instead of   :   `<div [hidden]="registerForm.controls['username'].valid"`

Hope this will help you :)